# Creating new entity framework record from related object

Tags: entity-framework

Is there a way to use SetValues() when creating an entity framework object.

I have a class with same field definitions as my entity framework class and found this explanation of an easier way to update ef records using the SetValues function.

https://researchaholic.com/2013/02/06/entity-framework-5-easier-way-to-update-record/

The question I have is this: Is there a similar way to create new ef records without specifying every field like this:

```
var newItm = new Import.EntityClasses.ImportSiteList {
    SiteId = ssItm.SiteId,
    OrganizationId = ssItm.OrganizationId,
    TimeZoneId = ssItm.TimeZoneId
};
tbl.Add(newItm);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can do

```
var newItm = new Import.EntityClasses.ImportSiteList();
context.Entry(newItm).State = EntityState.Added;
context.Entry(newItm).CurrentValues.SetValues(ssItm);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Hope it helps.